# unusual behavior with strings append property c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, data-structures

```
   #include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{


  string a ="hello";
  string b = "dear";

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
        string x = a.append(b);

  cout<<x<<" "<<b<<" "<<a<<endl;

}

}
```

> why value of a changing i am just changing x
>
> output::
>
> hellodear   dear   hellodear
>
> hellodeardear   dear   hellodeardear
>
> hellodeardeardear   dear   hellodeardeardear

Comment: `a.append(b)` modifies `a`.

Comment: Did you mean `string x = a + b;`? What is the output you expect? Edit the question to answer the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike strings in Python/Java/C#, C++ `std::string` is mutable. You can modify it in place without creating a new `std::string`.

When you call `append` member function, you're actually modifying `a`, and as it returns a reference to modified `std::string` you create a copy of `a` **after** it has been modified by `append`.

If you want to create a new `std::string` by combining `a` and `b`, do it like this.

```cpp
std::string x = a + b;
```